# Delete (http-only) cookies in R/Shiny

Tags: r, cookies, shiny, httpcookie

In Shiny, how can I delete a cookie that has "httpOnly" enabled? I'm having issues trying to expire Amazon’s "AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0" cookie.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

I found this question on the web, like: https://community.rstudio.com/t/problem-with-shiny-deleting-cookies/112385

However, no solution is available.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail how your app is being deployed? Do you know how the cookie is set in the first place? Are you using AWS to deploy your app? Related: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3524

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick, the link describes my problem. However I was not even aware of `session$request$HTTP_COOKIE`. So I will try this snippet to see what for cookies can be accessed.